# get_post_thumbnail with certain dimensions

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to get the attached images from posts with 250px width (the image size for thumbnails).

In the function.php file within the theme, I have the following lines:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size( 250, 200 );
```

so, in the uploads folder, I can see that besides the main image file, other format are generated, like filename_250x200.jpg and so on...

The question is that when I try to get the post thumbnail, i receive the original image.

This is the code:

```
wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID, 'post-thumbnails' ));
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wp_get_attachment_url` doesn't accept a size parameter. You need [`get_the_post_thumbnail`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/)

```
echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID,'post-thumbnails');
```

Comment: But also, JoostS is right... You should use `add_image_size` to define your custom thumbnail size

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing `set_post_thumbnail_size` with `add_image_size`. You should use the latter. Add this to your functions.php:

```
add_image_size( 'custom-size', 250, 200 ); // 250 pixels wide by 200 pixels tall, soft proportional crop mode
```

And then call in your template:

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'custom-size' );
```

More info: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/